# React Native Reanimated error: Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hi I recently created a react native app version 0.60.5 and installed react-navigation with react-native-reanimated. When I built the project in Android Studio, I'm getting this error in react-native-reanimated: `Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'`. Is there anything I did wrong?

Here's a screenshot:
[image: a]

Comment: Sadly, none of the provided solutions resolve the issue with me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
npm install -g jetifier
npx jetify
```

At root project. Thanks to Harsh2402 for his answer on this issue : https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/642

Answer (score 13):

This helped me out.

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

Comment: simple and effective, thanks a lot for support

Answer (score 2):

I had also the same issue but i fixed it by updating react-native-reanimated version 2.10.0 to 2.12.0
Thank you

Comment: It works for me. In my case, I'm using RN 0.68. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your android/build.gradle file

```
allprojects {

    repositories { /* ... */ }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.4'
        }
    }
}
```

When adding the code, make sure the react native version you have installed matches the version on this line: force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.4'

Answer (score 1):

Delete the node_modules and install again.

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

gradle.properties under android

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

run following command

```
npm install -g jetifier
npx jetify
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this type of errors

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED react native

This worked for me:

Add this in android\build.gradle

In file  check buildscript

buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2" must be updated

minSdkVersion = 16 `as per your updated version change into 21`

compileSdkVersion = 29

targetSdkVersion = 29

clear your gradle file

Delete the node_modules and install again.

npm i
npm run ios or
npm run android

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was that I didn't have installed the correct version of `buildToolsVersion` in the SDK Manager.
I have tried removing the library and running it again and then I saw that the minimum version requested for my project (due to some of the packages constraints) was 30 (R), so I had to upgrade the `buildToolsVersion` to 30.0.3 and setup `targetVersion` and `compileversion` to 30 and then it worked.

for

`"react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1",`

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3" // must be updated

minSdkVersion = 29 //must be updated

compileSdkVersion = 30

targetSdkVersion = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Force react-native-reanimated to use the version of root's react-native version by

```html
allprojects {

    repositories { /* ... */ }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.4'
        }
    }
}
```

And also change the version of react-native-reanimated to 2.10.0

It worked for me.

NOTE : It should be a comment but I do not have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing problem with reanimated library -

My problem was that my username on PC contains the '.'

Solution move your project inside 'C:\Users\youruser.name\projectName'

Then run commands to run application --
yarn
npm start
npm run android

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the method I've used to resolve this by deleting the node_modules directory,

```
rm -rf node_modules    // or you can delete in manually
```

and I run the cmd,

```
npm i --force
```

which solved my error.