# Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:androidJavadoc' in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to run the React Native Android App on a physical device. I'm giving it the command:

```
react-native run-android --deviceId=MY_DEVICE_ID
```

But it gives this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:androidJavadoc'.
> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'MyApp/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build/tmp/androidJavadoc/javadoc.options'
```

I've tried the solution mentioned here: [React Native Reanimated error: Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934866/react-native-reanimated-error-execution-failed-for-task-react-native-reanimat) I which I did `npm install -g jetifier` and then `npx jetify` and then in `gradle.propeties` I've `android.useAndroidX=true` and
`android.enableJetifier=true`

But it still gives the same error when I run `react-native run-android --deviceId=MY_DEVICE_ID`

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to `android/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
  tasks.withType(Javadoc).all { enabled = false }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why ? what does the statements do?

Comment: What if you don't want to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to create a new emulator with a higher API version